# Неясности с cookie в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код:

```
import os
import http.cookies

cookie = http.cookies.SimpleCookie(os.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE"))
name = cookie.get("name")
```

Для чего нужны: SimpleCookie, os.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE")?

Comment: Подозреваю, для начала вам надо почитать, что такое CGI

Answer (score 2):

Второй получает печенье, а первый его нарезает. Или какой ответ Вам нужен?